# Can't find /dist directory in Netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8

I'm trying to export a project as a .jar in NetBeans 8, and I realize it's supposed to save automatically. All the sources I've found point out that it should be located in `<myProjectFolder>/dist`,but that directory does not exist-- is there a setting I must toggle?

Comment: What kind of project? Standard Java SE Project? If so just clean and build. It will appear.

Comment: What build system are you using? Ant, maven, ...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to first clean and build to generate one.

As you do programming work you will see the result of your work , but this doesn't go into the **dist** folder **until you clean and build**.

Comment: Thanks. Coming from Xcode, I had no idea what "clean and build" meant.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project name in the NetBeans and you will see many options

starting with new, Build, clean and Build. click the clean and build and it will

create a dist folder which has the war file and you can access the dist folder

in the files at the top (projects Files Services)